# Write different user imput data in the same line on a txt file in C

Tags: c++, file, line

I want to write a simple program which collects data from user input to save into a txt file.
I've find several ways to collect and save the data but I couldn't find a way to write different instances from user input into the same line on the txt file.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    char book[30];
    char author[30];
    char quote[64];

  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("myfile.txt", ios::in | ios::ate);

    if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    cout << "Enter the name of the Book: ";  
    fgets(book, 30, stdin);

    cout << "Enter the name of the Author: ";
    fgets(author, 30, stdin);

    cout << "Type the quote: ";
    fgets(quote, 64, stdin);

    myfile << ("%s;",book) << ("%s;",author) << ("%s;",quote);

    myfile.close();
    }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";


  return 0;
}
```

The out put on the file is:

```
Book01
Author01
"This is the quote!"
```

I'd like to be in the same line:

```
Book01; Author01; "This is the quote!"
```

Thanks for you help and attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fgets` function includes the newline character in the buffer, so when you write them those newlines will appear in `myfile`.  You could simply remove the newlines with something like this:

```
book[strlen(book)-1] = '\0';
```

But mixing `fgets` with `cout` is a bit odd to begin with, so just get rid of it and use `cin` instead.  For example:

```
cin >> book;
```

Comment: The problem of `cin` and others is that they return only the first word, only through `fgets` I can retrieve the whole sentence especially for the "quote". The `strlen` worked fine! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the fgets doc: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

> A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a
>   valid character by the function and included in the string copied to
>   str.

So, at the end of the data readed, there is a \n